# Extracting SUM of data from XML in Sql

Tags: sql, xml, field

I have an XML field in SQL table like this

```
<Root>
 <Name>Apollo</Name>
 <Code>1000</Code>
 <Code>2000</Code>
 <Code>3000</Code>
</Root>
```

I need to write an SQL query to select the 'Name' and SUM of 'Code' values

```
SELECT 
 T1.c.value('Name[1] AS VARCHAR(100)') AS Name,
 T1.c.value('Code[1] AS NUMERIC(10,5)') AS TotalCode
FROM TableName
CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('Root') AS T1(c)
```

it gives me output like this:

```
Name                Code
---------------------------
Apollo              1000
Apollo              2000
Apollo              3000
```

But I need SUM of values of all the Code tags like this:

```
Name                Code
---------------------------
Apollo              6000
```

Any ideas how to get sum of tag values?

Comment: This by no means look like standard SQL. What database system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the most "elegant" and I'm sure there is a more direct route, but you can try this

```
Select
    B.Name,
    SUM(B.TotalCode)
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
       T1.c.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Name,
       T1.c.value('Code[1]', 'NUMERIC(10,5)') AS TotalCode
    FROM TableName
    CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('Root') AS T1(c)
) AS B
GROUP BY Name
```

Basically this first pulls the data out of the XML field items and then groups by Name and gives the sum.  Like I said, not elegant but works!

Comment: @Arpit, But `value` function requires 2 argument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx?

Comment: I had copied the OP's code for the query, I updated for proper syntax, so now those of you copying should be fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use this XQuery:

```
select t.xmlField.value('(//Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    , t.xmlField.value('fn:sum(//Code)', 'int')
from @t t
```

Sample data:

```
declare @t table(xmlField xml)

insert @t values('<Root>
 <Name>Apollo</Name>
 <Code>1000</Code>
 <Code>2000</Code>
 <Code>3000</Code>
</Root>'), 
('<Root>
 <Name>Apollo1</Name>
 <Code>1000</Code>
 <Code>2000</Code>
</Root>'),
('<Root>
 <Name>Apollo3</Name>
 <Code>1000</Code>
 <Code>2000</Code>
 <Code>13000</Code>
</Root>')
```

Output:

```
----------------------
Apollo     6000
Apollo1    3000
Apollo3    16000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 T1.c.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Name,
 T1.c.value('sum(Code)', 'NUMERIC(10,5)') AS TotalCode
FROM TableName
CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('/Root') AS T1(c)
```

Comment: Getting an error: XQuery [TableName.xmlField.value()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:SUM()'

Comment: @Arpit Do you use SQL Server?

Comment: My and Mikael's answers run well, while @Mitchel Sellers returns error... (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: @polish: Even if the accepted answer did run it would not return the correct result with the given sample data. It only sums the first code for each root node.

Comment: @polish Well... I can run the code posted by me :) but not the code posted in the question or the code in the accepted answer.

Comment: I too can run this code with using the the sample data script from KirillPolishchuk, but I need to change TableName to @t.