# SQL Server group by key and sum over an xml column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, xml-parsing

As stated in the title i have a table with a composed key (main key and position key) and a Value column that contain an XML (with a fixed schema).

The fixed XML appear like the subsequent :

```
 <Data>
     <ItemACount></ItemACount>
     <ItemBCount></ItemBCount>
 </Data>
```

Both ItemACount and ItemBCount represent positive integer number.

I would like group records that have the same main key (but different position key) then, for each group calculate the sum of each ItemACount and ItemBCount.

I write the SQL code as below :

```
SELECT
    MainKey AS MainKey 
    SUM ( [Value].value('/Data/ItemACount/@value') ) AS TotalItemACount ,
    SUM ( [Value].value('/Data/ItemBCount/@value') ) AS TotalItemBCount 
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblItems]
GROUP BY 
    [MainKey]
```

But I get a syntax error:

> Cannot find either column "Value" or the user-defined function or aggregate "Value.value", or the name is ambiguous.

I would like to understand which is the correct syntax.

Comment: Check this question already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786687/extracting-sum-of-data-from-xml-in-sql

Comment: @Rogério Carvalho my situation is a bit different i need to sum the field in the different xml (each field i unique per xml but is repeated in each row)

Comment: But the solution is the same, you can create a subquery to first return the values e and in the main query apply the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
   MainKey AS MainKey 
   SUM ( [Value].value(('/Data/ItemACount/@value)[1]', 'int')) AS TotalItemACount ,
   SUM ( [Value].value(('/Data/ItemBCount/@value)[1]', 'int')) AS TotalItemBCount 
   FROM [dbo].[tblItems]
   GROUP BY [MainKey]
```